# Profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-signals

Hi i working with Django .
I'm trying to turn my user into a profile with signals

When registering the user through a form

I get the following error :
**TypeError at /Registro/  Profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'** and
the user is created in 'AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION' (ADMIN),  but not in profiles.

*Models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombreUsuario = models.CharField('Nombre usuario : ',  max_length=15, null = False, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField('Contraseña',  max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    #Unique sirve para validar si el usuario existe y sea unico el email y nombre de usuario.
    nombres = models.CharField('Nombres', max_length=255, null= True, blank=True)
    apellidos = models.CharField('Apellidos', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='img_perfil/',default='batman.png',null=True, blank=True)
    fecha_union = models.DateField('Fecha de alta', auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    facebook = models.URLField('Facebook', null=True, blank=True)
    instagram = models.URLField('Instagram', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Perfil de {self.nombreUsuario}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Perfil"
        verbose_name_plural = "Perfiles"
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .models import Profile

from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

def iniciarSesion(request):
    return render(request,'social/inicio.html')

def registro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            user=fm.save()
            username = fm.cleaned_data.get('username')

            messages.success(request,'Registration Created Successfully')
            redirect('feed')
    else:
        fm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'social/registrarse.html',{'fm':fm})

def feed(request):
    return render(request,'social/feed.html')


def profile(request):
    return render(request,'social/profile.html')
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model=User 
        fields=[
                'username',
                'email',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                ]
```

***signals.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import Profile



def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        #group = Group.objects.get(name = 'profile')
        #instance.groups.add(group)

        Profile.objects.create(
            user = instance,
            name= instance.username,
            )
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**I need help with this code!**

Comment: Not really strictly related to your question, but now Django has [better ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) of extending the `user` model.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, you know how you could tell me about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what exactly did you expect? Your `Profile` model doesn't seem to have a fk to user and that's what you are trying to do (twice) in the signal.

Just add `user` fk to `User` model and create it once in the signal.